# Show/Hide Multiple Divs with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use some buttons to show/hide multiple divs using jquery.

The page will initially show all divs. The idea then is that there will be a button to reset (show all) and then separate buttons to show a particular div while hiding the rest.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="buttons">
<a class="button" id="showall">All</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div2">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div3">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div4">Lorum Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: See: [Example](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/jquery-show-hide-multiple-elements/)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#showall').click(function() {
    jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
  });
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <a id="showall">All</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Answer (score 24):

If they fall into logical groups, **I would probably go with the [class approach already listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery/6967112#6967112)**.

Many people seem to forget that you can actually **select several items by id in the same jQuery selector**, as well:

```
$("#div1, #div2, #div3").show();
```

Where 'div1', 'div2', and 'div3' are all id attributes on various divs you want to show at once.

Answer (score 9):

Assign each div a `class`. Then you can perform actions on all of them:

```
$(".divClass").hide();
```

So each button can do:

```
$(".divClass").hide()
$("#specificDiv").show();
```

You can make this more generic, and use the obvious convention - the button and the div with the same number in the id are related. So:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  var divId = "#div" + $(this).attr("id").replace("showdiv", "");
  $(".divClass").hide(); 
  $(divId).show();
}
```

Comment: if you get elements and save them in a variable and after if you want to hide, It do not work 

`let elements = $(".divClass");
elements.hide();`

Answer (score 3):

Just a small side-note... If you are using this with other scripts, the $ on the last line will cause a conflict. Just replace it with jQuery and you're good.

```
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
           jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
    });
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/4764/

Answer (score 1):

simple but stupid approach:

```
$('#showall').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').show();
});

$('#showdiv1').click(function(){
    $('#div1').show();
    $('div[id^=div]').not('#div1').show();
});
```

as for better one - add common class to all div's, and use some attribute in buttons with id of target divs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to show / hide singular divs and / or groups of divs with less code, just apply several classes to them, to insert them into groups if needed.

Example :

```
.group1 {}
.group2 {}
.group3 {}

<div class="group3"></div>
<div class="group1 group2"></div>
<div class="group1 group3 group2"></div>
```

Then you just need to use an identifier to link the action to he target, and with 5,6 lines of jquery code you have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Check This [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TdQMa/)

**Html:**

```
<div class="buttons">
<a class="button" id="showall">All</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#showall').click(function(){
    $('div').show();
});

$('#showdiv1').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});

$('#showdiv3').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
});

$('#showdiv4').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div4').show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, read this post, but ended building this solution that selects the divs dynamically by fetching the ID from a custom class on the `href` using JQuery's `attr()` function.

Here's the JQuery:

```
$('a.custom_class').click(function(e) {
  var div = $(this).attr('href');
  $(div).toggle('fast');
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

And you just have to create a link like this then in the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="#1">Link Text</a>
<div id="1">Div Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `target` attribute on the links just opened in new window, so I modified the accepted answer to the one below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('#showall').click(function() {
      $('.targetDiv').show();
    });
    $('.showSingle').click(function() {
      $('.targetDiv').hide();
      $('#div-' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="button" id="showall">All</a>
  <a class="button showSingle" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="button showSingle" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="button showSingle" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="button showSingle" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div-showdiv1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
<div id="div-showdiv2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div-showdiv3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div-showdiv4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>
```