# hidden div not loading javascript inside correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

I used jQuery shown here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6967175/1130782) to get the links on my page to show/hide 3 different divs, as seen here: http://ikstudio.squarespace.com/lightfield/

I needed all of the divs to be hidden initially, so I removed the #showall function and added

```
jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
```

to hide all the divs initially.  Doing this broke the javascript gallery I am using inside of .

I am assuming that this is because the page loads with that div hidden and the gallery script can not properly position everything it needs to.

Is there anyway to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you not hide them with CSS?

```
.targetDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I can and it has the same result.  The problem lies in javascript gallery trying to load into a div that is not show at the time.