# Using javascript on multiple Div Id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created an expanding div that hides on load and expands when clicked using javascript and jQuery. My problem is that I need to use this feature multiple times on each page (10-30x). Is there a way to call the function to work with multiple Div ids using an array or something of that nature (I am a newbie, my apologies), e.g. a few of my div ids would be eb1, eb2, eb3, eb4. and here is my script that currently works on one id:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {


        jQuery('#eb1').hide();
        //hides box at the begining
        jQuery("#hide").click(function() {
            jQuery('#eb1').fadeOut(300);
            //jQuery('#the_box').hide();
        });
        jQuery("#show").click(function() {
            jQuery('#eb1').fadeIn(300);
            //jQuery('#the_box').show();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, even a link to an explanation.
Thanks,
Travis

Answer (score 2):

Further to [John Conde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498438/82548) this is also possible using attribute-starts-with:

```
jQuery('div[id^="eb"]').hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GJpJ7/2/).

It is, of course, easier to just use a particular class-name, and the selector then becomes:

```
jQuery('.className').hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GJpJ7/3/).

References:

- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by separating the ids with a comma:

```
jQuery('#eb1','#eb2','#eb3').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

just type "jquery multiple div show hide" into google:

the first link gives this:
[Show/Hide Multiple Divs with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery)

:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is cleaner to add a css class to all the `div` (or whatever tag you use) elements that should behave like that, then use that class in the selector ?

```
        jQuery('div.hidable').hide();
        //hides all 'hidable' boxes
        jQuery("#hide").click(function() {
            jQuery('div.hidable').fadeOut(300);
        });
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to do that.

let me explain

> function ToogleDiv(container){
>
> ```
> // simple toogle
> $(container).toggle();
>
> // a toogle with some effect
> $(container).toggle('slow', function() {
>  // add some action    }); }
> ```

here's is a Jquery example [Toogle Jquery Example](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
var divs = $('div[id^="eb"]');
$(divs).hide();

$('#show').click(function(){
    $(divs).show();
});

$('#hide').click(function(){
    $(divs).hide();
});
```

Live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJBUM/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(var id){
     jQuery(id).fadeIn(300);
}

function hide(var id){
     jQuery(id).fadeOut(300);
}
```

and then, in your divs:

```
<a id="hide" onClick="hide('eb1')">hide</a>
<a id="show" onClick="show('eb1')">show</a>
<div id="eb1"></div>
```