# Create faq acronym with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, acronym

i want to faq page like this http://videoguard.pt/en/support/#section2

i am doing this

**THIS IS MY HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FAQ ACRONYM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="section1">
        <ul class="sec1-style">
            <li><a href="#f1">I completed the payment process online but did not receive an order confirmation. Did you receive my order?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#f2">I still have not received my items, when will I get them?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#f3">How do I change my address?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#f4">How do I cancel/change my order?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        <ul>
            <li id="f1"><p>If you have received an on-page confirmation, this means your order did go through. Do check your spam box to see if your order confirmation was filtered there by your email server.</p></li>
            <li id="f2">On average, local deliveries should reach within 1-3 working days. If has been more than 3 working days, do send us an email with the delivery address and invoice number so we can do a status check for you.</li>
            <li id="f3">Log in with your Handymon account and update the changes under my personal details. However if you have just purchased under your old address and would like to re-direct the package, please drop us an email at askme@handymon.com as soon as possible. We will try to cancel/modify your order before it is mailed out.</li>
            <li id="f4">Please drop us an email at askme@handymon.com as soon as possible. We will try to cancel/modify your order before it is mailed out.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**THIS IS MY CSS**

```
#main
{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto;
    }

#section1
{
    width:50%;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid red;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#section2
{
    width:49%;
    height:600px;
    float:right;
    border:2px solid grey;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

HELP ME  i am stuck i want to do like this http://videoguard.pt/en/support/#section2 guide me how to do this

Comment: You're not stuck my friend.. You haven't started it.  In your case you don't even need jQuery, simply try it using with css styles.

Comment: aaah!! same question again! check this link.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery`.

Comment: how to do with css but i want slide effect too check this link i want like this http://videoguard.pt/en/support/#section2

Comment: where is the slide effect in the link you provided?

Comment: no slide effect sorry but i want to create my faq like this pls guide me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For slide effect use **[jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/show/)**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/sk37b/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     var link= $(this).attr("href");
     $("#section2 ul li").hide();
     $(link).show("blind");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#section2 ul li').hide();
    $('#section2 ul li:first').show();
  $("a").click(function(){
      var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#section2 ul li').hide();
    $(target).toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor script problem. try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#section2 li:not(:first)").hide();
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#section2 li").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```