# Add a target attribute with a loop

Tags: javascript

I have an input button where is written within a blade foreach loop in a laravel project.

```
<div class="v-percentage">
       <input id="copycode" type="Submit" value="Embed">
</div>
```

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to add a target attribute on the input so each button would be unique, and do something like this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery). The script I wrote so far it should get the element and then within a for loop to add the target which i am not sure yet how I should do this.

```
var elements = document.getElementById('#copycode');
  alert(elements);
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  {
    //add the target to the element
  }
```

Also, when I alert the elements is returning null. How can i work that out?

Comment: `getElementById` does not need a `#` in there.

Comment: id are unique, you will only receive one element, habitually the first. Also getElementById need a string without the #. So var element = document.getElementById('copycode');  If you want to select many elements, you are better with a class and var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('theClass');

Comment: Please do not edit in a solution in the question. You can post your own answer if you need to add more information for the solution than is posted in an existing answer. And you can leave Rocket's answer marked as accepted, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('copycode')
```

`getElementById` just wants the ID, not a CSS selector.

Also, this will return *one* element (*not* a NodeList).  IDs are *unique* throughout the page.  If you want to select multiple elements, use classes and `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

the Javascript function getElementById only returns one element. If you are trying to get a set of elements, try to use a class

```
<input class="copycode" type="submit" value="Embed" />
```

Then you could use a jquery selector to get the set of elements and iterate over then

```
$(".copycode").each(function(key, element){
    element.attr("target", "foo");
});
```

If you don't want to use jquery, use the javascript function getElementsByClassName and a for to iterate over the set of elements

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("copycode");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].setAttribute("target", "foo");
}
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery being used here... And while we are on the subject, `e` in this case is the `index`. You mean `this` instead.

Comment: That's much better :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have more than one ID with the same name, ID should be unique per page.
   The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.
2. If you want get all the input element then you should try getElementsByTagName()
   The getElementsByTagName() method accesses all elements with the specified tagname.
   document.getElementsByTagName("input");

   ```
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   alert(elements);
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
   {
   //add the target to the element
   }
   ```

   Hope this helps!