# Toggle multiple divs one at a time with 1 button using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four divs which i want to toggle one at a time with a single button. I want to toggle them one after the other and not randomly. I have tried something like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#1').hide();
  });
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#2').hide();
  });
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#3').hide();
  });
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#4').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.divs {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='1' class='divs'></div>
<div id='2' class='divs'></div>
<div id='3' class='divs'></div>
<div id='4' class='divs'></div>

<button id='toggle'>
  toggle
</button>
```

Comment: I want to hide and unhide each and every div one after the other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide Multiple Divs with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery)

Comment: Click once, toggle one button? Or click once, toggle four buttons one by one?

Comment: toggle 4 divs one by one like. click the button hide first div click the button again and unhide the first div. then click the button hide the second div then click the button and unhide the second div and so on..

Comment: Hey @girish added the code. You can go through it once and comment on the same for further clarifications. Hope the code will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the state on each click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var state = 1;
  $('#toggle').click(function() {

    if(state==1){
       $('#1').hide();
       state=2;
    } 
    else if(state==2){
       $('#2').hide();
       state=3;
    }
    else if(state==3){
       $('#3').hide();
       state=4;
    }
    else if(state==4){
       $('#4').hide();
       state=1; //back to state
    }
  });
```

Comment: this worked for me with slight changes.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('.divs:visible:first').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle').click(function(){
        $('.divs').show();
        if(count == 4)
            count = 1;
        $('#' + count).hide();
        count++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, keeping numeric ids is not good, so considering you will change them after wards, I am writing both the answers with numeric ids and without numeric ids.

**With Numeric Ids, it is easy to do**.

Suppose you have button to toggle the other four divs then it would look like this:

```js
var state = 1;
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
   $("#"+state++).slideToggle();
   if(state===5){state=1;}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='1' >1</div>
<div id='2' >2</div>
<div id='3' >3</div>
<div id='4' >4</div>

<button id="toggleButton">
 toggle
</button>
```

**Now coming to the non numeric ids.**

```js
var state = 1;
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
  $("#div"+state++).slideToggle();
  if(state===5){state=1;}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1' >1</div>
<div id='div2' >2</div>
<div id='div3' >3</div>
<div id='div4' >4</div>

<button id="toggleButton">
 toggle
</button>
```

**FYI:In my opinion you should not use numeric ids.**

---

Further adding more in to the code.

If you don't know how many div would be there but you are having a clear cut rule that the div's **follow the sequence** whether or not **they are having numeric/non numeric ids** then you can **change the code slightly to incorporate that** as well like this.

```js
var state = 1;//first button id to be toggled
var total = 4;//this will be the total number of divs to be handled by the button
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
  $("#"+state++).slideToggle();
  if(state===(total+1)){state=1;}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='1' >1</div>
<div id='2' >2</div>
<div id='3' >3</div>
<div id='4' >4</div>

<button id="toggleButton">
 toggle
</button>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of Id for using many times

```js
var i = 1;
$('#toggle').click(function(){
  $('.divs').show();
  $('#' +  i).hide();
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='1' class='divs'>dsgsdg</div>
<div id='2' class='divs'>64636</div>
<div id='3' class='divs'>46y</div>
<div id='4' class='divs'>4373477</div>

<button id='toggle'>
  toggle
</button>
```

Comment: that will hide all the divs on a single click. I want to hide single div one by one on the button click

Comment: @girish - I updated the answer for your context check and let me know if you have any isues

Comment: toggle 4 divs one by one like. click the button hide first div click the button again and unhide the first div. then click the button hide the second div then click the button and unhide the second div and so on..

Answer (score 0):

loop through each element and use toggle. This gives the effect that you desire.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.divs').filter(function(index,item){
  $(item).toggle('slow')
 })
})
```

Have a look at this demo - 
https://jsfiddle.net/ukw5wcmt/

Answer (score 0):

```
  var i = 1;
    $('#toggle').click(function(){
      $('.divs').show();
      $('#' +  i).hide();
      if(i==4)
        {
        i=1;
        }else{
        i++;
       }
    });

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id='1' class='divs'>dsgsdg</div>
    <div id='2' class='divs'>64636</div>
    <div id='3' class='divs'>46y</div>
    <div id='4' class='divs'>4373477</div>

    <button id='toggle'>
      toggle
    </button>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
 .hide{ display: none; } 

  $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".click-btn").click(function(){
          var fid = $(".hide:first").prop("id");
           $("#"+fid).removeClass("hide");  
        });
        
        $(".remove-tag").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
        });
    });

    <div id="cart-1" class="hide">
        <div class="remove-tag">x</div>
        <h5>1</h5>  
    </div>
    
    <div id="cart-2" class="hide">
        <div class="remove-tag">x</div>
        <h5>2</h5>  
    </div>
    
    <div id="cart-3" class="hide">
        <div class="remove-tag">x</div>
        <h5>3</h5>  
    </div>
    
    <div id="cart-4" class="hide">
        <div class="remove-tag">x</div>
        <h5>4</h5>  
    </div>
    
    <div id="cart-5" class="hide">
        <div class="remove-tag">x</div>
        <h5>5</h5>  
    </div>
        
    <button class="click-btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Try adding some explanation along with your answer! Use the edit button bottom left of your answer to add details.