# jQuery - ForEach function on rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, foreach, innerhtml

I have the following JS/jQuery which grabs the cell value of an ASP DetailsView control (rendered HTML), checks it for a condition, and hides a div based on said condition. It is basically checking to see if the cell value is formatted like an IP address or not...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Grab innerHTML in the IPAddress cell from DetailsView1
    //See if it contains the characters: 10.
    //If it does not contain '10.', hide the parent div for that user
    var ip = document.getElementById("DetailsView1").rows[3].cells[0].innerHTML;
    var addrFormat = ip.includes("10.");
    if (addrFormat == false) {
        $("#IDofDetailsView1ParentDiv").hide();
    }
});
```

This works well, but I need to check several DetailsView controls, and potentially .hide() several elements by ID.

In JS/jQuery, is there a way to:

*ForEach rendered HTML element like DetailsView, check format condition, then hide parent div for this control only, if condition is false*

Thank you for any advice.

***EDITED TO SHOW MARKUP***

Here is the rendered HTML I am working with...

```
<div class="square" id="myId">
<div class="content">
    <div><p id="myId2">Unavailable for Dispatch</p>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div id="UpdatePanel1">
            <div>
        <table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="DetailsView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2" style="border-style:None;">Text1</td>
        </tr><tr align="center">
            <td class="building" colspan="2" style="border-style:None;">Text2</td>
        </tr><tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2" style="border-style:None;">Text3</td>
        </tr><tr align="center">
            <td class="hide" colspan="2" style="border-style:None;">Text4</td>
        </tr><tr align="center">
            <td class="hide" colspan="2">Text5</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have several of these on my page. Right now I am using:

```
var ip = document.getElementById("DetailsView1").rows[3].cells[0].innerHTML;
```

But I will probably need to use a class selector on "Grid" to process them all at once, correct?

Then I need to hide the very highest div by id, not the closest parent. But ONLY hide those divs whose td 'Text 4' value is false. I am not sure how to grab the innerHTML I am currently getting from "DetailsView1", if I use the Grid class instead.

Thank you again...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery) can help

Comment: `$(elementsSelector).filter(function(){ //return true if their format is invalid }).closest(parentSelector).hide()`

Comment: Most jQuery.fn methods perform an implicit for each on the result stack of the jQuery object they operate upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses for each and then use 'this' to target individual elements.

EDIT: Had to edit this and removed includes() as it does not work in very many browsers. Now I am converting the HTML of all .Grid elements toString() and then I use indexOf() on that string to determine if it contains 10.

New working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5kenge/

Updated Code:

```
   $(function(){
          $('.Grid').each(function(){
          var string = $(this).html().toString()
          console.log(string)
            if (string.indexOf("10.") > -1) {
              $(this).closest('.square').hide()
            }
            })
            })
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I am not a pro with JS/jQuery, but it looks like you are using a class selector for the each method...can you look at this markup I added in my edit above, and should I be able to use the $('.Grid') to select the class, and still get the cell value I need? Also, I need to hide the highest div in the markup, not the closest parent. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, now using .Grid as the selector for .each and it then grabs the "closest" .square div and hides it

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand your suggestion, you are saying that the above function should check each .Grid class element in the document to see if they include '10.' somewhere in their table, and if not, hide the closest .square div? That is how I understand your function, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Do I need to somehow include innerHTML, for (a poor) example, something like $(('.Grid).innerHTML).each(function()... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162544/discussion-between-m0lochwalker-and-jpeg).

Comment: Ok, check my updated answer with included JSFiddle - working like a charm now.

Comment: This is awesome, your answer works. I did have to change > -1, to === -1, for it to work as I need. I want to hide any div that does not contain 10., where your fiddle does the opposite. But it works a charm!! Thank you!!