# Show/hide multiple partial views on same page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, show-hide

I have a dashboard kind of page where on the left you would have menu items like:

- link 1
- link 2
- link 3

Each of them going to a different action in the same controller.

I would like to have each action render it's data in the same page (in partial views) but I have no idea what the "best" way of doing this would be.

So lets say link 1 is rendering a list of people (table), link 2 statistics (charts) and list 3 some configuration properties.

How should I define this so that on each click, the main frame (which is the menu bar on the left containing the link 1-2-3 and is defined in a shared view) stays but only the middle content (partial views) would change, keeping in mind that link 1 is a table, link 2 charts and other controls and link 3 a bunch of controls (textboxes, drop down's and so on).

Should I show/hide div's on each click? This seems/feels kind of dirty to me?
All input/suggestions are very welcome!

EDIT: 
This is the behavior I want (accepted answer): [Show/Hide Multiple Divs with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery)

**Note**: I am using C# in an ASP.NET MVC project and I would prefer a C# ASP.NET MVC solution (Javascript if needed), not other script/coding languages or frameworks.

Comment: See [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/07/01/simplifying-single-page-applications.aspx) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/single-page-application-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/) as 2 of many examples.

Comment: @SteveGreene thank you for the examples. I think this is slightly to complicated for me, I really thought there would be a simpler way of handling this with partial views ... Guess I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have implemented this answer: [Show/Hide Multiple Divs with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery) since the other ones are not in my direct knowledge to implement them

Code sample:

```
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery('#showall').click(function() {
  jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
 });
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
   jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
 });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <a id="showall">All</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/

I am still open to other suggestions, specially if they involve Partial views and not to much of other things.
Thank you all so far!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an onClick Handler on a Link:

```
<a onClick="handleLink1()">Link1</a>
```

Assuming the Rigth side locks like this:

```
    <div id = "renderArea">

    </div>
```

With that you could write the handleLink1() Functio nas follows:

```
function handleLink1(){

//Here you asign the new HTML:
Document.getElementById("renderArea").innerHTML = "<div/>";

}
```

Now you can write an Function for every Link and rerender the Rigth Part as you wish.

Comment: I tried this but clicking the link(s) doesn't do anything. My links (<a>...</a>) are in a shared view (layout.cshtml) and so are my functions. The <div id = "renderArea"> is in another View that has a partial view in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ether PHP or Java for this kind of Setup.
Alternativly you could use an JS Framework like Angular or React, they can Handle it as well.
For Plain JS you can alsways use an Event (The Links gets clicked) to change the Page as you wish.

Comment: I can't use PHP, React or TypeScript since i don't know these languages, but can you tell me more about the Javascript approach? I can't possibly imagine that this would be the only option in my setup? Thank you for your feedback!